# How to log to diferent files with Log4perl

Tags: perl, logging, perl-module, cpan, log4perl

In perl, is there a way to log to two different files in different path?

For example, I have to log detailed server queries and responses in a file and flow of the script in other file (the second file will have just the abstract information). How do I achieve this in Log4Perl.

```
sub getLogger
{
    my ( $paramA, $paramB, $type ) = @_;
        my $conf = ("
            log4perl.rootLogger =INFO, LOGFILE
            log4perl.rootLogger1 =ALL, REPFILE

            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE=Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.filename = sub { getLogFileName(\"$paramA\", \"$paramB\", \"$type\"); };
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.mode=append
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.autoflush = 1
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.size      = 1M
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout=PatternLayout
            log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c] %d %H - %m%n

            log4perl.appender.REPFILE=Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.filename = sub { getLogFileName(\"$paramA\", \"$paramB\", \"$type\"); };
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.mode=append
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.autoflush = 1
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.size      = 1M
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.layout=PatternLayout
            log4perl.appender.REPFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c] %d %H - %m%n
        ");
        Log::Log4perl::init(\$conf);
        my $logger1 = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('rootLogger');
        my $logger2 = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('rootLogger1');
        if($type == 1)
        {
            return $logger1;
        }
        else
        {
            return $logger2;
        }
}
```

When I try to get logger1 and logger2 at different places of the script, the last obtained instance copies to both loggers. For example,

```
my $logger1 = getLogger($paramA, $paramB, $type);
$logger1->info("This is log 1"); #printed in file 1 correctly
my $logger2 = getLogger($paramA, $paramB, $type);
$logger2->info("This is log 2"); #printed in file 2 correctly
$logger1->info("Again trying to print in file1"); #printed in file2 - expected to print in file1.
$logger2->info("Again trying to print in file2"); #printed in file2 - expected to print in file2.
```

I am stuck here. What is going wrong?!

Comment: follow the standard [here](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html#c7fa8)